# How do I rebind a reference from a destructuring statement?

Tags: rust

I can create a rebindable reference to one of a struct's members using the `mut` keyword as follows:

```rust
struct Entry {
    data: u32,
    id: u32,
}

let e = Entry { data: 0, id: 0 };
let mut reference = &e.data;
// rebind reference to e.id
reference = &e.id
```

However, it doesn't seem possible to rebind a reference from a destructuring statement. Is this the case? I would expected the following to be valid syntax but it fails.

```
// ok: reference is &u32
let Entry { id: reference } = &e;
// fails:
let mut Entry { id: reference } = &e;
// rebind reference to e.id
reference = &e.id;
```

[Obligatory playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e6a2604eb2bbc05dff1b92c22cc3f141)

Comment: You cannot use `mut` binding on Patterns please check: https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/patterns.html#struct-patterns

Comment: It looks like your question is the same as [Is it possible to create a mutable value of a mutable reference in a pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49710608/155423), which is to say there is no way other than the workarounds. If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as a duplicate.

Comment: @Shepmaster it is basically the same question. I can't mark it as a duplicate though since the other question doesn't have an accepted answer.